# Is there a way to change the zoom of a website with javascript if the users display settings scaling is set over 100% forexample: 125% 150%?

Tags: javascript, html, windows

[Here are the display settings I meant... It is always set on laptops to 150%...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZurc.png)

Is there a way to change the zoom of a website with javascript if the users' display settings scaling is set over 100% for example: 125% 150%?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale elements using transform scale:

.example-element {transform: scale(150%)}

but screen scaling as you mean is handled in the browser.